# How to remove system files that are marked read-only?

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive, read-only

I have a pendrive which is full of viruses. These viruses are `.js` files. Using linux, I can open the pendrive and see which folders they are in. But when I try to remove them by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> button or via `sudo rm filename.extension` it gives me an error:

```
cannot remove 'file.lnk' : Read-only file system
```

All of the files on the pendrive are like this. I can't even format it with [gparted [image: Install gparted]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) but it also gives me an error message.

I have like 3 or 4 folders containing these `.js` files. I can even open it with [gedit [image: Install gedit]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit) but can't edit its contents. These folders' names are like:

- `C4`
- `d8d8d`
- `cfc4c`

...and the files are like:

- `gd586d.js`
- `id9d9.js`

How can I work around this? I would like to remove these files from the pendrive by terminal or any another method.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting from GParted?

Comment: @hmayag Sorry, actually I get the error when I try to format via *Disks*. The Gparted format option is Unable.

Comment: You should press `Unmount` button before `format`

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov on *Disks* ? I did it...

Comment: what happens if you run `Benchmark Drive...` in `Disks` ?

Comment: If you were ready to fortmat it, then try yo delete partitions from _Disks_, _Gparted_ or by _fdisk_. If _fdisk_ then run it with `fdisk /dev/sdX` where _sdX_ of your pendrive (`dmesg` will show when you plug it or you can see  from _Disk_ and _Gparted_). Then press `p` and then answer with numer of partition to be deleted.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov I tried to delete partition from gparted and it was processing for over 30minuts, then I ejected the pendrive and closed the gparted.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov If I trie to run benchmark: *An Error Ocurred: Error readin 10,5MB (x bytes) from offset 80.00MB (y bytes) (g-io-error-quark,0)* And if I try to format from disks: *Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object(udisks-error-quark,0)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your pendrive device is dead. I am pretty sure, because all times I saw I/O error it meant hardware was damaged.

Comment: I also think so... I have 2 pendrives with the same problem (vírus). The first one I could remove easily with linux live cd, but this second one... No way! And I'm used to see this model of pendrive with problems and stop working... Look, I could get all the importante files from the pendrive and moved to my HD. Even if I Could do so it still may be damaged?

Comment: You didn't move all files, but if so, there might be physical sectors damages regardless whether they are occupied or not. The IO error is very serious problem, related to a hardware.